# "Type or Namespace definition, End of File expected" Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I was working on a Unity project and I got the Titles Error I don't know what I did to get this error but it is painful for me trying to figure this Error on my own. I tried rewriting the area of code that made this error message and this did not work.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D theRB;

    public float movespeed = 5f;

    private Vector2 moveInput;
    private Vector2 mouseInput;

    public float mouseSensitivity = 1f;

    public Camera viewCam;

    public GameObject bulletImpact;

    public int currentAmmo;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Player movement
        moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector3 moveHorizontal = transform.up * -moveInput.x;

        Vector3 moveVertical = transform.right * moveInput.y;
        theRB.velocity = (moveHorizontal + moveVertical) * movespeed;
        //player view control
        mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y")) * mouseSensitivity;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z - mouseInput.x);
        viewCam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(viewCam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles + new Vector3(0f, mouseInput.y, 0f));

        //Shooting Code
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (currentAmmo > 0)
            {
                Ray ray = viewCam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, .5f, 0f));
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    //Debug.Log("I'm looking at " + hit.transform.name);
                    Instantiate(bulletImpact, hit.point, transform.rotation);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Im looking at nothing");
                }
            }
            currentAmmo --;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is the end bracket that is showing the red error squiggly lines.

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many closing curly brackets. Try removing the curly bracket on the line immediately before
`currentAmmo--;`

Edit: adjusted answer based on comment below.

Comment: I would say it needs to be the bracket before, the one after closes the if button pressed, I dont think he wants to subtract ammo even if he doesnt have enough ammo.

Comment: this is the answer I am looking for